# How to automate Excel sheets?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to update my Excel file using other Excel files.

I have a bunch of Excel files open in my project and I am trying to merge all the files as spreadsheets inside one Excel document instead of having multiple Excel files in my project.

This is what I have so far:

```
tbody = soup('table', {'class':'ss-text'})[0].find_all('tr')
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    #CSVList.append(cols)
    writer.writerow(cols)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
with open(filename[ab], 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save(filename[ab] + '.xlsx')

wb1 = load_workbook('Definitions.xlsx')
wb1.create_sheet(filename[ab] + '.xlsx')
wb1.save('Definitions.xlsx')
```

Comment: looks like you are using openpyxl to write your excel file. Why not use `wb = Workbook()` and create worksheets **before** you read from other files?

Comment: Maybe can find some help here?: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: I would look into the xlrd and xlwt packages. A lot easier to use. https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt

Comment: @AntonvBR I am using the book. It's helped thus far but the author didn't mention any case resembling what I am attempting to do.

Comment: @cowbert I initially used the Workbook method, but could not achieve what I was aiming for. Also, I have tried the XlsxWriter library.

Comment: if you provide a better example of what you expect the output excel to be, it will be easier to answer

Comment: *This is what I have so far:* ... so what is not working? And please include all `import` lines.